# Understanding service.rs in substrate-node-template

Tags: substrate-node-template, grandpa, aura, service

Recently, I have been trying to understand the block import for Aura and Grandpa but I don't understand some parts in substrate-node-template/node/service.rs:

1- In the `new_partial()` method when initializing Aura [import queue](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/e0c480c0f322d0b0d1b310c93fa646fc0cfdd2df/node/src/service.rs#L105), why is Aura using grandpa_block_import, isn't Aura supposed to just create blocks and should not care about justifications or finality because that's what [import_block](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_consensus/block_import/trait.BlockImport.html#tymethod.import_block) method does of `GrandpaBlockImport`? In the `new_full()` method, when starting Aura, the same thing happens, we are again using grandpa_block_import passed via [block_import](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/e0c480c0f322d0b0d1b310c93fa646fc0cfdd2df/node/src/service.rs#L237)

2- Why would Grandpa execute blocks again or check them if we are using the same block import, shouldn't Grandpa just vote on chains using block hashes and not care what's inside the block because that's the job of Aura? because this way it should instantly finalize all aura blocks since its the same block import but is not, so what is import_block() actually doing?

having one block import is a bit annoying because imagine if you want to write your custom block import logic that does some custom verification before passing it to Aura only and not grandpa, if a majority of validators accept the block in aura, grandpa would simply finalize it by importing it directly with no verification, this would be impossible currently as they are executing the same logic.

3- I'm tempted to import the block directly via the [client](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_service/client/struct.Client.html) in the Aura import queue in `new_partial()`, then let grandpa do the finalization with grandpa_block_import in `new_full()`  Meaning even if aura rejects a block it should be imported if grandpa finalized it, would that be wrong? if so, how to achieve that? because there is a note to use it carefully which I don't fully understand

> NOTE: only use this implementation when there are NO consensus-level
> `BlockImport` objects. Otherwise, importing blocks directly into the
> client would be bypassing important verification work.

4- what does no consensus-level BlockImport objects mean?

Answer (score 1):

In the `new_partial()` method when initializing Aura [import queue](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/e0c480c0f322d0b0d1b310c93fa646fc0cfdd2df/node/src/service.rs#L105) it doesn't actually use grandpa's block import, it uses a grandpa's decorated block import. Block imports implement a chain of responsibility pattern (well kind of).

The very last guy is always the [client](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/14e0a0b628f9154c5a2c870062c3aac7df8983ed/client/service/src/client/client.rs#L1751). If you need to add some extra logic to that chain you create a new block import and the previous becomes [nested](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/14e0a0b628f9154c5a2c870062c3aac7df8983ed/client/consensus/grandpa/src/import.rs#L61). Now you can do additional checks, throw errors and [fallback](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/14e0a0b628f9154c5a2c870062c3aac7df8983ed/client/consensus/grandpa/src/import.rs#L540) to the nested block import if needed.

So what happens in the `node-template`

1. client (default block import) is created (**client**)
2. grandpa wraps it with its own block import, applying his specific logic. (**grandpa -> client**)

That is why you have to use `grandpa_block_import` otherwise grandpa's logic is not executed.

Since Aura is a very simple consensus it doesn't apply any specific logic of its own. Take a look [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/14e0a0b628f9154c5a2c870062c3aac7df8983ed/bin/node/cli/src/service.rs#L207) instead. It uses both babe and grandpa. So the chain is **babe -> grandpa -> client** and obviously you have to use the last `block_import` to execute the whole chain.